# Question about integrability and inequalities

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing

> Let $f \colon [a, b] → R$ be a bounded function that is integrable in
> $[a,b]$.
>
> Show that if  $Mf = \sup \left\{f(x) | x ∈ [a, b]\right\}$ and $mf = \inf \left\{f(x) | x ∈
>  [a, b]\right\}$
>
> then $M|f| − m|f| ≤ Mf − mf $.

I've been trying to prove this for a while and I'm lost.. how do you show something like that?

Comment: First prove $$M (f) - m (f) =\sup\, \big\{|f(x) - f(y) | : x, y\in[a,b]\big\}$$ as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/452986/591889), then by triangle inequality we know that $$\big||f(x) |-|f(y) |\big|\leq \big|f(x) - f(y) \big|.$$ Therefore it follows that $$M (|f|) - m (|f|) \leq M (f) - m(f) .$$

Comment: Not quiet sure on how to prove the first part..

Comment: you don't really need the first part in the comment from Sumanta. The accepted proof given in the link is enough.